# How do I connect to an IRC server behind NAT using Android phone?

Tags: ssh

I use a private IRC server that is behind a NAT. Currently, I SSH into a server with a public address and use a command line IRC client in a tmux session to connect to the private server. Is there a way using only android apps to connect to the protected server using an IRC client on the Android phone through an SSH tunnel? I am not rooted but I am also not against rooting.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this:

1. Run an SSH client on your phone, such as ConnectBot
2. Forward a local port to the remote IRC server, say `localhost` port `1234` to `irc.server.ip:6666`. ([Directions for ConnectBot, with screenshots](http://tech.shantanugoel.com/2010/08/02/ssh-tunneling-android.html))
3. Connect your IRC client to `localhost:1234`, instead of `irc.server.ip:6666`. If this doesn't work, check that you have permissions.

When your connection's not working, you will have to do some extra debugging to check that the SSH tunnel is still up. But otherwise, you should be able to use any IRC client.